# Order By DAY() Doctrine Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I,m using [Beberlei DoctrinExtensions Bundle](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) to do queries with DAY(), MONTH() and YEAR() on Symfony2.

Everything works on selects. But, when I try to make some OrderBy, I got a Syntax Error.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT a FROM AppUserBundle:User a WHERE MONTH(a.dataNascimento) >= MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND DAY(a.dataNascimento) >= DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) 
    ORDER BY DAY(a.dataNascimento)
```

And the error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 151: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

Without ORDER BY clause the query works.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you can't use functions within DQL `ORDER BY` clauses (even though you can within SQL). The way around this is to add the field to your `SELECT` clause with `HIDDEN` so that Doctrine doesn't return that and shift your results into mixed mode. So your DQL would be:

```
SELECT a, DAY(a.dataNascimento) AS HIDDEN myday
    FROM AppUserBundle:User a
    WHERE MONTH(a.dataNascimento) >= MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        AND DAY(a.dataNascimento) >= DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) 
    ORDER BY myday
```

Doctrine never explicitly states this in their documentation however a similar example is hidden away on the [DQL page](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples).